# How to set default file encoding of source file in qt creator?

Tags: qt, encoding

There is no [image] default file encoding option in my qt creator. Therefore, every new created file is inherited from the system encoding, which is gbk(cp936) on my windows box. But I want to set the default file encoding of the source files to utf-8. How?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that even if you change the encoding to "UTF-8" it may still display "System".  From Qt's Creator documentation on the web: "Default encoding field still displays the value System if the default system encoding is set to UTF-8".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found that option in the text-editor plate.[image]

*Note: after changing the encoding to "UTF-8", it may still display "System" if your system encoding is UTF-8.  The Qt creator documentation states "Default encoding field still displays the value System if the default system encoding is set to UTF-8".*